# Instrumental variable “weak instrument”

Tags: instrumental-variables

When z is a weak instrument:

Do you have an insignificant OLS estimate for pie1 ?

Further more:
When x is a binary variable is it always the case that the sample IV estimator can be written as y1-y2 (the ols estimator?)

I’m assuming this is only the case when z is also a binary variable?

Comment: How is $y1-y2$ the OLS estimator? Please define all your notation.